# Reactjs hiding a select tag based on an option in another select

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am new to Reactjs.I am trying to hide a Select tag with div classname(DropDownButton3) till option (Three) in select tag with div classname(DropDownButton2) is selected.Here are my .jsx and css files please help me.

.jsx

```
<div className='DropDownButton2'>
 <label style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>Second</label>
 <br/>
 <select defaultValue={-1} style={{width: '300px', height: '35px'}}>
   <option disabled value={-1}> </option>
   <option value='One'>One</option>
   <option value='Two'>Two</option>
   <option value='Three'>Three</option>
 </select>
</div>

<div className='DropDownButton3'>
 <label className='hide' style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>Third</label>
 <br/>
 <select className='hide' defaultValue={-1}>
   <option disabled value={-1}> </option>
   <option value='A'>A</option>
   <option value='B'>B</option>
 </select>
</div>


.css

.DropDownButton2 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.DropDownButton3 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
```

Comment: do you want to hide only using css?

Comment: Can css hide elements based on input values?

Comment: no I want to hide it based on the selected option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have the values of the dropdowns stored in state, try the following:

```
<div className='DropDownButton3'
  style={ {display: this.state.dropdown2 === "Three" ? "block" : 
"none"} }
>
```

You can also use the classnames plug in if you wanted to do more style than just hiding it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

EDIT: I'm assuming there is a state involved because there must be something controlling the state of the select.

Comment: The code snippet in the question does not mention any use of `state`. You are referring to non-existent `state`.

Comment: What is controlling the select then?

Answer (score 0):

implement

```
change = (event)=> {
    this.setState({selectedButton: event.target.value});
  };
```

add

```
<div className='DropDownButton3' style={{display: this.state. selectedButton === "Exchange" ? "block" : "none" }}>
```

and add onChange to DropDownButton2. and this should work perfectly fine.